# Azure Cosmos Document DB, possible to have relational links?

Tags: database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document DB that follows the following rough json structure:

```
{
    id: 32,
    Name: 'John',
    Occupation:{ 
        name: 'Programmer',
        hours: 40
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have a separate document collection or something similar that occupation can relate to? Such as:

```
{
    id: 32,
    Name: 'John',
    Occupation: 'jobs/JOB_PROGRAMMER_ID'
}

// jobs document collection
{
    id: 'JOB_PROGRAMMER_ID',
    name: 'Programmer',
    hours: 40
}
```

I can write out a backend querying function which will automatically resolve these relationships but was wondering if there was an inbuilt way to do this.

Comment: It is certainly possible to do so however please keep in mind that you will only be able to query one collection at a time. Cross-collection queries are not supported AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do with Cosmosdb.Only thing is that without having multiple collection, you need to embed within a collection as explained below.

> Relational databases are not the only place where you can create
>   relationships between entities. In a document database you can have
>   information in one document that actually relates to data in other
>   documents. Now, I am not advocating for even one minute that we build
>   systems that would be better suited to a relational database in Azure
>   Cosmos DB, or any other document database, but simple relationships
>   are fine and can be very useful.

**[Embedding documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data)**

Comment: You don't need to embed documents to have relationships between documents (and, if it's an unbounded number of embedded documents, this can lead to app failure when exceeding maximum document size).  It may simply lead to multiple queries. And related documents can live either in the same collection or in different collections.

Answer (score 1):

You can store any type of references you want, within a document. However, as @gaurav mentioned in his comment, you will need to create additional queries to follow these relationships (whether in the same collection or in different collections).

Queries (as well as stored procedures) are scoped to a single collection (more accurately, to a single partition, although you *can* have cross-partition queries). They cannot span multiple collections; this would be up to you to interpret your reference (whether a path, an id, etc) and then use this as the basis for your follow-on query.

If multiple queries are impractical for your solution, you would need to devise some other scheme (such as denormalizing, where you would store a subset of related data within your document, as a subdocument or collection of subdocuments). Note: with embedded documents, if the number of embedded documents is unbounded (e.g. no limit, like comments for a blog post, or replies to a tweet), you run a risk of exceeding maximum document size, which will break your app once this happens (unless you have alternative logic for storing content beyond a single document's size limit).